# Brakes for a mountain bike frame (26'r) with 27" road wheels

Tags: brakes, commuter

I have converted a mountain bike to a commuter. the frame accommodated 27 " wheels, so I installed for a better ride. I have a road carbon kinesis fork up front with a v-brake, but need a rear brakeset.

The boss positions for the rear brakes, however, are too low on the seat stays for a standard set of v brakes to properly contact the rim.

Is there a brake that is long enough to contact a 27" rim when installed on a 26" mountain bike frame?

Comment: That's quite a bit of difference. My guess is that if the brakes did reach that far, the extra length would cause the arms of the brakes to flex quite a bit every time you applied them.

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried, but at Paul Components say these [Moto BMX brakes](http://www.paulcomp.com/motobmx.html) might work with 700c rims on 26" frames. But they might turn out to be too expensive for your purpose.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean 700c (622mm), not the obsolete 27" (630mm) size.

You could try the "WHEEL V BRAKE EXTENDER" from http://www.thorusa.com/accessories/wheels.htm or a similar idea from Lite_pro http://www.thecyclopedia.com/resources/LitePro-v-brake-adaptor.jpg

Personally, I'm not very convinced by them, but I haven't tried them. The Paul Moto BMX are probably a safer idea. (These http://dx.com/p/aest-ultralight-bicycle-v-brake-front-rear-caliper-set-blue-144195 also look as if they allow more adjustment than standard V brakes, but it might not be enough.)

If you do use something like the Paul Moto, you might want levers designed for old-style cantilevers, because the mechanical advantage will be very different from a standard V-brake setup. (Edit: scratch that, Paul's instructions say use brakes designed for direct-pull (i.e. V-brakes).)

Edit: A couple more adapters that look a bit better designed to me: http://www.xtracycle.com/cargo-bicycles/xtracycle-cargo-accessories/small-parts/v-brake-adapter-700c.html http://urbanvelo.org/mavic-700c-brake-post-adapter/

Comment: Also, you could consider using a caliper brake, assuming you've got relatively thin tyres now and if there's a brake bridge with a mounting hole. But since you've got V's in the front, that would mean mismatched levers, as well as the now unused bosses looking untidy.

Comment: And a few more options for adding studs:
http://leagueofbikepolo.com/forum/general/2012/10/19/diy-v-brake-adapter-for-center-mount-frames
http://www.ratrodbikes.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=33168&st=0&sk=t&sd=a&start=30
http://www.danscomp.com/489051.php?cat=PARTS
http://www.bentechbikes.com/vbrakes.htm

Comment: Yet another one:  http://bmxmuseum.com/forsale/42379#.UVwh1JBDvZg